# Why is my project calling another projects code?

Tags: vba, excel, project, add-in

Currently I have two versions of an excel addin - The released version, and the current WIP version.

When I load both into Excel and try to run the released code, it calls my WIP code instead, which is rubbish for testing. When I open the code in VBE I can still run the subroutines as intended.

I looked for information on projects calling other projects code, but all I found was how to do this, not why it happens/how to stop it. It may be due to both projects having exactly the same subroutine and function names, but surely those of the current project should take precedence?

Currently it is just an annoyance, but it leads to confusion upon testing. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to stop this behavior by specifying the module name for each subroutine.
Apparently this is a know bug with .OnAction, as it calls from whichever workbook (and I assume module) was loaded most recently. Thanks, for the help, it seems I didn't realise where the bug was!

Answer (score 0):

In VB Object Browser, goto References and uncheck reference to unwanted code.

Comment: When I check references for the released version it does not include the current project. If I prefix with the module name, then it works, but I shouldn't have to do that with internal code right?

Comment: Do you have any code that runs when you open the workbook (Workbook_open)

Comment: On Auto_Open it calls AddMenus, similar to this: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/custom-menus.htm

Answer (score 0):

Excel remembers where the code pointed to, so it will continue to work even if the reference is unchecked - you will also notice that if you rename the add-in, the functions will return `#NAME!` instead of using the current version.

A quick way to force Excel to re-evaluate where it gets the code from is to do a search and replace, and change `=` to `=`. This results in the same formula, but forces excel to update its links so the current accessible version is found

(extrapolated from [PRB: Automation Add-In Function Binds to Excel Built-In Function with the Same Name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286305))

Comment: These subroutines are being called from a menu bar, and even after changing the WIP module name, if I stop explicitly using the current module in the released version they use the WIP code.